# is there a way to crash a docker container deliberately?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm running a web app as a container and I'm storing the logs generated by this app in a file. But the log file generated by the app is created inside the container file system , So to access these logs when the container crashes I'm using docker volume, so that i have access to log files even if the container crashes.But i want to test if this really works when the container crashes , So any help on how to test would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I am wanting to do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact that docker containers are also processes, you can probably get the pid of the process by using `ps aux` and a `grep` on the container name.

After this you can simply `kill -9` it. This should break it pretty hard.

Comment: Thanks Meijers. Actually I was also thinking the same, but was wondering if it is really the same as a crash?.

Comment: It depends what you define as a crash, if it is simply the application inside a container crashing, the container itself stopping or the daemon that's running it.  Basically they all have their own separate pid which you can kill.

If it about you application, you could also add a method which you can trigger which simply crashes your app

Comment: @J.Meijers I have tried the above for a .netcore application and it doesn't crash the container, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969217/how-do-i-stop-a-net-core-app-inside-docker?noredirect=1#comment94776436_53969217

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

1) Stop the container:

```
docker stop container_name
```

2) Kill the container

```
docker kill container_name
```

Comment: Thanks Akki. But I want the container to stop abruptly. What you are suggesting is not really a crash, docker stop or kill would stop the running container normally. Doing so I would still be able to access the container file system by restarting it.