# How do I stop a .net core app inside docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I want to create a crash inside my .net core application.  I used `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` which works fine when I run the application using `dotnet run`.  Although if I run the app inside a docker container, the application continues to function happily.

I am open to ideas on the best way to do FIT (fault injection testing) for .net core.

Any ideas?

PS: I have also tried creating a `StackoverflowException` but it doens't cause a crash while running in docker

Comment: Are we talking about a .NET Core console application or is it an ASP.NET application?

Comment: It's an ASP .net core web api.  I have a feeling it will be the same problem with the console app too, I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Well, ASP.NET handles exceptions for you and prevents crashes (in most scenarios) because you obviously don't want your applications to crash. A console application on the other hand does this not for you. So it might actually be different there.

Comment: Strange, because the app crashes when not run inside the docker container just fine, so I don't think that's the reason.

Comment: Did you test the application outside the container under the same conditions (environment, debugging mode, ...)?

Comment: @Namoshek: Yes, I have tried both, in `Debug` and `Release` configurations.  Environments obviously cannot be the same as one is inside a docker container